# dbt: access a source column's tests as specified in a source schema.yml

Tags: dbt

where do column-level schema tests live in the graph?

I ask because I'd like to set the null-ability of a column in a CREATE TABLE statement based on the presence of a `not_null` test for a column.

for example, how might I determine if a column in the `customers` table below has a `not_null` test or not?

my idea was something like this

```py
{% set source_nodes = graph.sources.values() if graph.sources else [] %}
{% for node in source_nodes %}
    {%- set columns = source_node.columns.values() -%}
    {% for column in columns %}
        {%- set nullity = 'NOT NULL' if 'not_null' in column.tests else 'NULL'-%}
```

but the column dict has the following properties and `'test'` is not a key in the `column` dict.

```py
{
    'name': 'id',
    'description': 'Primary key of the table',
    'meta': {},
    'tags': []
}
```

where is the test info?!?

#### example source `schema.yml`

```yaml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: raw_jaffle_shop
    description: A replica of the postgres database used to power the jaffle_shop app.
    tables:
      - name: customers
        columns:
          - name: id
            description: Primary key of the table
            tests:
              - unique
              - not_null
```